# Converting the fetched data using fetch() to JavaScript array of maps

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to fetch the contributors of a GitHub repository using GitHub API and JavaScript. I am able to fetch the data but I need that data as JS valid data type so that I can manipulate it according to my needs. The fetched data is basically array of objects so I am not able to use it as an array of Maps.

```
async function fetchData() {

const token = '<GitHub Token>';

fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/Bitwarden/mobile/contributors', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `${token}`
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

}
//let data = new Map(Object.entries(fetchData()))
const data = fetchData()
let map1 = new Map()
for(let i=0;i<30;i++) {
  map1.set(data[i], data[i].contributions)
}
console.log(map1)
```

It is giving the error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: fetchData(...).values is not a function
    at script.js:19:26
```

Can anyone help me convert the fetched array of objects to an array of maps so that I can use it throughout the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner:

```js
const data = (await fetchData()).map(obj => new Map(Object.entries(obj)));
```

About `fetchData`, it needs to be modified a bit:

```js
async function fetchData() {
    const token = '<GitHub Token>';

    const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/Bitwarden/mobile/contributors', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `${token}`
        }
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
}
```

Comment: It's saying 
script.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: fetchData(...).map is not a function
    at script.js:19:26

maybe it is not returning an array of objects. Can you please tell me how to return it in the first place?

Comment: It's still giving me the same error

Comment: Are you sure that you awaited for both `fetch()`, `response.json()` and `fetchData()`?

Comment: how to know if I did that? (I m sorry I might seem dumb because I have really no idea about this. This is my first time doing JS and I am supposed to make a project using it)

Comment: Count if there are three `await`s in your code, each one before a function. If yes, then you're good to go.

Comment: yes I did await for fetch(), response.json() and fetchData() but now its giving me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'fetchData' (at script.js:15:21) on the await fetchData() line

Comment: There are three await. but then I am getting the error as I said in the previous comment
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'fetchData' (at script.js:15:21)

Comment: It seems that the platform you're using doesn't support top-level await. Try wrapping all of your code in a IIFE function, like this: `(async function() { /* code goes here */ })();`

Comment: done. I am getting an array of maps now. Thank you. but only problem left is whenever i am trying to console.log(data[0].contributions) or something like that, it's giving me Undefined

Comment: That's because `data`'s elements are `Map`s, and `Map`s' values need to be getted via the `get` method: `console.log(data[0].get('contributions'))`.